# leaflet map rotation (typescript)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, leaflet

I using leaflet.js map at my angular 2 (typescript) project.

there is any news about the whole map rotation ?

I already tried the CSS "Hack".

there is a leaflet or some plugin else way ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i find a solution !

I left leaflet just because this map rotation :(

because of that I use openlayers map. you can install in very simple way by this steps

```
npm install openlayers
```

Then install types openlayers to your dev env:

```
npm install --save-dev @types/openlayers
```

Then import to the file by this line:

```
import * as ol from 'openlayers';
```

finally you can use openlayers map like this:

```
new ol.Map();
```

(you can use code from [openlayers docs](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/doc/)).

Answer (score 1):

There is some discussion and experimental branches referred in [this Leaflet issue](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/268), but currently it is not supported by Leaflet.

Comment: there is other "hacks" except css ?

Comment: or some plugins that i can use ?

Comment: Not that I know of for Leaflet. OpenLayers does support map rotation: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/rotation.html

Comment: is OpenLayers is need money to use like mapbox and google maps ?

Comment: No, it's open source just like Leaflet.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/fnicollet/Leaflet/tree/rotate-master unnoficial leaflet branch supported rotation.

Comment: Thank u but i tried this one already,
and I also moved to openlayers, so i not need that anymore.

Comment: when I tried to use it i got a lot of errors are you can send me a working ionic 2 example ?